# IVR Programming Library for C#

Tags: c#, c++, ivr

I want to write a program that responds to calls.  After a welcome message it must tell the client to: press 1 for enter your account number, or 2 for speak with an operator.  If the client presses 1 then tell him or her to enter your account number and after he or she enters the account number the number must saved in the database.

Is this possible in c#?  If it is, I want an IVR library for c#.  If not, I need a great IVR library for c++.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has the [Microsoft Speech API (SAPI)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Tellme/developers/default.aspx?tab=desktop) however if you want simple IVR it is better not to reinvent the wheel and customize an [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) implementation (which i guess falls under the "great IVR library for c++" category (it's c not c++ but if you know c++ you should be able to understand the c).) Using [AsteriskNow](http://www.asterisk.org/asterisknow) you may not even need to write any custom code, it may do what you want already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a free IVR library for C#, but I do know of a couple that are fairly inexpensive:

http://www.voiceelements.com/

http://www.componentsource.com/products/velocity/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from the Twilio crew here.

We have a [tutorial on building an IVR with C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/csharp/mvc), taking a look at this may be helpful in getting an idea in how to build this type of application.

Whenever a phone call comes into our phone number, a request is made to our server where we can respond with some basic instructions, using [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), on what to do with the call:

```
        public TwiMLResult Welcome()
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();
            response.BeginGather(new {action = Url.Action("Show", "Menu"), numDigits = "1"})
                .Play("http://howtodocs.s3.amazonaws.com/et-phone.mp3", new {loop = 3})
                .EndGather();

            return TwiML(response);
        }
```

Since we're using the  [verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather), when the user presses a digit a new HTTP request will be made to another route on our server where we can take action based on what digit(s) the user pressed:

```
    public TwiMLResult Show(string digits)
    {
        var selectedOption = digits;
        var optionActions = new Dictionary<string, Func<TwiMLResult>>()
        {
            {"1", ReturnInstructions},
            {"2", Planets}
        };

        return optionActions.ContainsKey(selectedOption) ?
            optionActions[selectedOption]() :
            RedirectWelcome();
    }
```

Hope that helps!